# Spark SQL - select nested array values

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a bunch of Parquet files containing the following structure:

```
data
|-- instance: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- dataset: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- item: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
```

and I want to do some data manipulations using Spark SQL.

I cannot do something like

```
data.select("data.instance.dataset.name")
```

or

```
data.select("data.instance.dataset.item.id")
```

because nested arrays are involved and I get an error:

`Array index should be integral type, but it's StringType;`

I can understand why it is that, but what is the way to traverse nested structures in Spark SQL?

I could read/deserialise it all into my own class and then deal with it, but it is a) slow and b) doesn't allow people who use things like spark notebook etc to work with the data.

Is there any way to do it with Spark SQL?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I eventually swapped to a hiveContext and used explode to retrieve the array vaues, but im sure there is a better solution to this ... there must be